# Submit Extjs form via PUT Method

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to submit extjs form via HTTP PUT method?
I want to update record on Rails 3, which accept PUT method to update.

Here is my code:

```
formData.submit({       url: "/layers/" + param.layer_id + "/rules_property_thresholds/" + param.id ,
        method:'PUT',
        params: param,
        waitTitle: "Please wait...",
            waitMsg: 'Updating rule property threshold...',
                    .........
             });
```

I place method PUT but the request still doing POST when I check on Firebug(Net).
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only HTML5 is supporting `PUT` via the form directly. Forms up until now only support `GET` & `POST`.

For now you need to use ajax to submit the form via `PUT`:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'your url', // you can fix a parameter like this : url?action=anAction1
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
            myField1: myField1.getValue()
            // all your params.... 
        }
        success: function (result, request){
            alert('Succesfully added ' + result.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (result, request){
            alert('Error in server' + result.responseText);
        }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but from my understanding the following might work:

```
myForm.on('beforeaction', function(form, action) {
    action.options.method = 'PUT';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

i don't know anything about rails...
but I'm used to in couchdb like this

```
var a = {
    _id : "gordon",
    xtype : "user"
}

Ext.Ajax.request({
    method : "PUT",
    url: "/db/egy",
    jsonData : a,
    success : function(){
    console.log("aaa");
    }
});
```